# import worksheet according worksheet number

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have to import one excel file having 8 worksheet in it, but i need to import only second worksheet. Worksheet name will not be same every time as i always need to import Sheet2

If i am giving the name of the worksheet then it is importing successfully but i don't want to import through specific name, i want to import according to worksheet number 2

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "P_TEMP", strFName, False, "Sheet2!A2:N"
```

P_TEMP is table name, strFName is file name

Comment: I doubt something general like DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet will satisfy your rather specific requirement, and expect you'll need to perform your import more manually. Is P_Temp a permanent table? Is the data in the worksheet being imported in a constant format? I could give you a simple example, or if you can provide more information.

Comment: yes P_temp is permanent table and data in the worksheet is in constant format, Only the name of the sheet will change but it will be the second worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a more elegant solution, Access not being my area of knowledge, but you need to ascertain the worksheet's *name* from it's index, and at the very least this should be possible if you instantiate Excel so that you can use it's methods/properties to get the sheet's name:

```
Dim shtName as String

With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    shtName = .Workbooks.Open(strFname).Sheets(2).Name
    .Quit
End With

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "P_TEMP", strFName, False, shtName & "!A2:N"
```